# preg_replace: Greedy and ungreedy the same?

Tags: php, preg-replace

my code is:

```
$s = '<div style="text-align: justify;">Some text</div>';
$s .= '<div style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</div>';
$s .= '<div style="text-align: justify;">Some more text</div>';
$t1 = preg_replace("/<div(.*)>&nbsp;<\/div>/isU", "REPLACED", $s);
print $t1;
$t2 = preg_replace("/<div(.*)>&nbsp;<\/div>/is", "REPLACED", $s);
print $t2;
```

The idea is: I want to remove all divs with only & nbsp; in it.

The problem: No matter if I set the modificators to greedy or ungreedy (/U), the result is always:

```
REPLACED<div style="text-align: justify;">Some more text</div>
```

Why is this so and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify regex:

```
$t = preg_replace("/<div[^>]*>&nbsp;<\/div>/is", "REPLACED", $s);
```